# IAM Custom policies use cases in context to ec2.

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I am exploring `IAM` in `AWS`, I want to write custom policies for the users belonging to different class.

Can somebody provide with the common use cases so that i can write my own custom policies for users in context to ec2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In case of EC2, you can use IAM roles to prevent credentials being passed in code or in configuration. You also use IAM to tell who has access to EC2 (probably EC2 alone and say not S3), without sharing the master AWS credentials

Pointing to another answer I made for a similar question on stack-overflow for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21854096/2959100